# How to forward HttpServletRequest headers to another REST API in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, header

I have an REST API which accepts request headers in request. My controller is internally calling another API. What i want to do is pass all headers that i am getting in request to internal API that controller is calling.

I know that i can iterate over header and set them in HttpRequest that I am creating but is there any other way to set in a single step.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You can set headers as below :-

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(new MediaType[] { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON }));
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
headers.set("custom-header-name, "value");

HttpEntity<Request> entity = new HttpEntity<Request>(request, headers);

RestTemplate template = new RestTemplate();

ResponseEntity<Response> respEntity = template
    .exchange("URL", HttpMethod.POST, entity , RestResponse.class);
```

Comment: This is not what i asked. I am getting headers in input to my API that i need to pass to another api. Here you are creating headers in the code itself.

Comment: Then why don't you set like HttpEntity<Request> entity = new HttpEntity<Request>(request, headers);

Comment: I am using HttpClient. I know it's strange but when using RestTemplate, api doesn't consider the access_token that i am passing and returns 401. HttpClient works fine.

Comment: 401 does not means api is not acepting access token or any other header, but it means that there is something wrong due to whixh access token is not getting validated.

Comment: It only gives issues with resttemplate. As i switched to httpclient it started working fine.